# No test server found for this combination of app and calabash version. Recreatin g test server

Tags: android, ios, calabash

I was trying to run calabash-android .. getting error like below..

```
No test server found for this combination of app and calabash version. Recreatin
g test server.
2013-06-11 18:08:22 - "/bin/keytool.exe" -v -list -alias samplekey -keystore "c:
/testproject/calabash/sample" -storepass sample
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/calabash-android-0.4.6/lib/calabash-android/
helpers.rb:140:in ``': No such file or directory - "/bin/keytool.exe" -v -list -
alias samplekey -keystore "c:/testproject/calabash/sample" -storepass sample (Er
rno::ENOENT)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/calabash-android-0.4.6/lib/cala
bash-android/helpers.rb:140:in `fingerprint_from_keystore'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/calabash-android-0.4.6/bin/cala
bash-android-build.rb:3:in `calabash_build'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/calabash-android-0.4.6/lib/cala
bash-android/helpers.rb:49:in `build_test_server_if_needed'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/calabash-android-0.4.6/bin/cala
bash-android-run.rb:16:in `calabash_run'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/calabash-android-0.4.6/bin/cala
bash-android:76:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/calabash-android:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/calabash-android:23:in `<main>'
```

Please some one help me how to run calabash-android sample application on windows.. I am new to this tool.Thanks for advance.

Comment: Do you have the ANDROID_HOME variable set up? What is the output of the command `echo %ANDROID_HOME%`?

Comment: Where is keytool.exe? "/bin/keytool.exe" doesn't sound like a plausible location. Is it ../bin/keytool.exe? Could you post the exact command you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to be set and added to the path. Calabash is looking for keytool to sign the test server apk.
Make sure you have also `ANDROID_HOME` set and added to your path.

Comment: Hi varun: I have added already like android_home added : c:\android\sdk and java_home added like : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin.

Comment: So you created an environment variable but did you add it to the path? Just type keytool on cmd prompt and see what it says.

Comment: make your `java_home` like `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45` and add `%java_home%/bin` to your path.

Comment: Hi Varun, I had set java home like that only. Now it is working.. thanks you sharing your experience.